# import css from node_modules with webpack target node

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, server-side-rendering

I'm currently building a react app with server side rendering. I'm using some libraries that come with css files. When I try to import them like this:

```
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
```

I get the following error in my `server.js`:

```
/my/app/path/node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css:3
.leaflet-pane,
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.__webpack_exports__.a (/my/app/path/server.js:725:18)
```

Importing with

```
import '../../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
```

works.

Is there some way to configure webpack that I can import those css files normally?

Here's the webpack config for `server.js`:

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const postcssImport = require('postcss-import');
const cssnext = require('postcss-cssnext');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/server.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'server.js',
    path: __dirname,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          presets: [
            'react',
            ['env', {
              modules: false,
              targets: {
                node: process.versions.node,
              },
            }],
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: [
                postcssImport,
                cssnext,
                cssnano({
                  safe: true,
                  autoprefixer: false,
                }),
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        use: ['url-loader?limit=100000'],
      },
    ],
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
};
```

Comment: Is there any reason you don't use `style-loader`?

Comment: @IzumiSy `style-loader` doesn't work for server side rendering since it tries to access window which doesn't exist in node. I tried `isomorphic-style-loader` but that has the same problem as I described above.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've been trying to fix this for a while now...

Comment: @DaveMackintosh not really. I don't have that problem currently because I removed leaflet from my project.

Comment: hmm, yeah. I just loaded my stylesheet wrapped in an `if (typeof window !== "undefined) require("thing")`. Shame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an issue of `webpack-node-externals` which prevents bundling all resources located under `node_modules` directory.

You can use the `whitelist` option to avoid this behavior.

Here is an example from [documentation](https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals#how-can-i-bundle-required-assets-ie-css-files-from-node_modules) of `webpack-node-externals`:

```
...
nodeExternals({
   // load non-javascript files with extensions, presumably via loaders
   whitelist: [/\.(?!(?:jsx?|json)$).{1,5}$/i],
}),
...
```